# What are these, and why wont they die?

Tags: identification, weed-control, weeds

My yard has become somewhat infested with these weeds.  Trimec Classic at 1.5oz/gal seems to damage them, but not kill them.  Much of my yard is tiffway 419 bermuda, with some remaining fescue, so the kinds of chemicals I can use seems a bit limited.  I'm in the north-central area of North Carolina.

If anyone can tell me what these are, and what chemical, or blend of chemicals, will kill them and not harm the bermuda, it would be greatly appreciated...

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: he bottom picture are violets, a hardy weed.

Comment: If it was my lawn, I would be doing some digging in the area with the most weeds. Depending on the size of the lawn, of course. Chop  up the weeds, add some grass seed, water, mow, lather-rinse-repeat.

Comment: I didn't plant violets and they've sprouted up in a few places.  Weed or not, shouldn't trimec classic kill them?  And if not, any idea what would (and not the grass)?  Thank you

Comment: @BobaFit It's almost an acre of grass with the weeds scattered all throughout.  The weeds don't own the yard, but they have popped up all over so I'm trying to find the right chemical/mixture that can remove them.  I thought trimec classic would be it, but apparently not.

Comment: Different herbicides work differently. Some only kill certain plants, and some only during certain growth phases. Read those labels carefully!

Comment: Thanks!  Any idea on what the other two pictures are?

Comment: on an established lawn like that, your best bet is to wait until next year until early spring or later winter and apply a pre-emergent herbicide. I would over-seed this fall in anticipation of some cross-die-off; it's impossible to do scalpel-level surgery on an area so big, so it's more of a numbers game where you can tilt the odds to your favor. Meanwhile,  you might be able to somewhat reduce them this summer with weed-b-gone or weed-n-feed.

Comment: I put out prodiamine last august and again in February.  I put it out at .367oz / 1000sf.   It's controlled a lot of weeds, but those pictured above are giving the good fight.  Hoping if I can identify what they are I can maybe choose a better herbicide(s).

Comment: In my experience, no chemical kills violets, not even RoundUp. You must dig them by hand, and you need to do this before their seeds mature because the seed heads "shatter", scattering seed up to a foot away from the mother plant. Well, theoretically, RoundUp could kill them if you continue applying it at weekly intervals, but of course your lawn would be well dead by then.

Comment: I think the first picture might be Parsley-piert and the second picture is fireweed.  Can anyone confirm this,?

Answer (score 1):

First weed is probably something endemic to your area, second weed is what we in Wisconsin call "burnweed" (a rayless composite with an ugly flower that sets air-borne seeds), and the third is, as noted in the comments, a violet. Let the burnweed get tall, then hand pull it. It's an annual so if you don't let it go to seed and have neighbors upwind who don't have it, then it'll be gone next yeear. You'll have to hand-dig the violets; I recommend a Japanese garden knife (AKA a *hori-hori*) because the point allows you to pierce the lawn without damaging it.